# CSS transform rotation is not smooth

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have a css transform on a toggle. The transform rotates the image 90 degrees then on toggle rotates it back. Rotating to 90 is nice and smooth but the way back is jumpy. What am I not getting? Here's my code and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqWLV/) with rtc.

CSS:

```
.rotate1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
     -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0);
}

.rotate2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
     -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
       filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
}
```

JS:

```
$("img").on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("rotate1 rotate2");
});
```

Comment: Have you tested this across various browsers? If so, is this issue persistent across the board, or is it browser specific?

Comment: IE9 and Firefox are the only browsers we will be using this in. The problem is evident in Firefox, in IE9 it's not smooth both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a class to the image.

```
<img src="..." class="rotate1" />
```

Here's an update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bqWLV/1/

Answer (score 2):

You are toggling both "rotate1" and "rotate2" to activate and deactivate simultaneously when you invoke `toggleClass("rotate1 rotate2")`.

Instead, add the "rotate1" class to your HTML element and only toggle the "rotate2" class.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Jav8/)

Comment: Any suggestions for making it smooth in IE9?

Comment: IE9 doesn't support CSS3 transition. You'd have to abandon this approach and go for something like a jQuery animation function.